# How to merge multiple object of child class to single parent object

Tags: c#

I have created four classes inside a single parent class. Since all the child classes have the individual properties which we need to assign to different values
and we need to merge all the objects of child class to parent class so help me in creation and pass the single object inside a method argument.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. _Also, please put the code into the post as text rather than as a picture._

Comment: Show us your classes... write them in your question, mark them as code, having them as a picture makes it really difficult for people to edit your code (copy and paste it back to you). Show us also the method call you have tried, and the generation of the class that creates the objects. (In short, what you have tried, all of it...)

Comment: *"Child classes"* would indicate that they derive from the parent class, which they do not in your code - you have 4 nested classes. Also it's unclear what you mean by *"merge"*

Comment: You must explain better what you want your end result to be. The terms you use, like "merge" and so on aren't clear in this context by themselves.

Comment: (All) the fields are `static`, so what's even the point of trying to "pass" anything as a method argument?

Comment: If these are not just some test classes, wouldn't it make more sense to have one `public class X { public string name; public int age; }` and then another `public class A { public X B; public X C; public X D; public X E; }`? -- then you could create an instance of `A`, fill the fields `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` with (separate) instances of `X`, and then pass that instance of `A` around wherever you want it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have now is not *child* classes, but *nested* classes. You want neither. You probably want this:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
  public Person B { get; set; }
  public Person C { get; set; }
  public Person D { get; set; }
  public Person E { get; set; }
}

internal static class Program
{
  private static void Method(A a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(a.E.Name);
  }

  internal static void Main()
  {
    var a = new A 
             {
                B = new Person { Name = "Peter", Age = 31 }, 
                C = new Person { Name = "Paul", Age = 78 }, 
                D = new Person { Name = "Mary", Age = 24 }, 
                E = new Person { Name = "Jane", Age = 15 } 
             };

    Method(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for your ans.